# Stock Correlation Matrix Quantmod

Tags: r

I want to run a correlation matrix in R stemming from `getSymbols(c("AAA","BBB","CCC", ...)`, $AAA.Close for a somewhat large list of stocks in QuantMod.  Any ideas on how to set this up as a script or specific command line?  Much obliged.

Comment: One of the primary issues is dimensional mismatching, given some symbols are newer than others.  Does R have the functionality to default to the latest Close data for any paired correlation?

Comment: You would probably need to merge on the index values. NA's would then get removed in the default for `merge` which is an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

The merge component was properly addressed in a previous forum.  So, the following works:

```
stocks <- c("AAA","BBB","CCC")
getSymbols(stocks, from="xxxx-xx-xx", to="xxxx-xx-xx")
ClosePrices <- do.call(merge, lapply(stocks, function(x) Cl(get(x))))
correlations <- cor(as.matrix(ClosePrices))
```

However, I'm still getting a ton of NAs due to missing closing prices for recently listed stocks compared to older symbols.  I'd like to perform a correlation analysis for any pair using the most recent data starting point in the pair as startdate.

Answer (score 0):

solved...

```
cor(ClosePrices, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

Amazing what a little due diligence will accomplish.  Thanks for viewing/responding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this.

```
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

symbols <- c("AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG")
getSymbols(symbols)
stocks <- data.frame(as.xts(merge(AAPL, MSFT, GOOG)))
stocks$date <- row.names(stocks)
row.names(stocks) <- NULL

# head(stocks)

jan31 <- ymd("2016-01-31")
days_to_keep <- jan31 %m+% months(0:11)
# days_to_keep

res <- stocks %>%
  select(ends_with("Close"), date) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  filter(date %in% days_to_keep)

res %>% select(-date) %>% cor()

#            AAPL.Close MSFT.Close GOOG.Close
# AAPL.Close  1.0000000  0.9198357  0.9313001
# MSFT.Close  0.9198357  1.0000000  0.9103830
# GOOG.Close  0.9313001  0.9103830  1.0000000

# Or more visually...
res %>% select(-date) %>% pairs()
```

Or...this...

```
require(quantmod)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)

symbols <- c("DBC", "EEM", "EFA", "GLD", "IWM", "IYR", "SPY", "TLT")
getSymbols(symbols, from="2016-01-01")

prices <- list()
for(i in 1:length(symbols))
{
    prices[[i]] <- Ad(get(symbols[i]))
}
prices <- do.call(cbind, prices)
colnames(prices) <- gsub("\\.[A-z]*", "", colnames(prices))

returns <- Return.calculate(prices)
returns <- na.omit(returns)

result <- table.Correlation(returns, returns)
result <- result[,1]

corMatrix <- matrix(result, nrow=length(symbols), ncol=length(symbols), byrow=T)
corMatrix <- round(corMatrix, digits=2)

dimnames(corMatrix) = list(colnames(prices), colnames(prices))

write.csv(corMatrix, file="CorrelationTable.csv")

print(corMatrix)
```